# How to delete item seleted in table product

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am trying to delete a product, but it's doesn't show success. I do not know how to get the id of that product to delete

My button `onClick = {handleDelete}` is import from component in other folder. I try to create `handleDelete` function, but I missing something in this case.

This is my code for that section

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import Loading from "../../components/Loading";
import Button from "../../components/Button/index"
import firebaseApp from "../../api/config";

const ProductTableList = ({
  products,
  loading,
  fetchProductRequest
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductRequest();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);


const firebaseDb = firebaseApp.database();
const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Loading />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }

 

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const productId = firebaseDb.ref().push().key;
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure to delete this record?")) {
      firebaseDb
        .ref("products")
        .child(`products/${productId}`)
        .remove((err) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else setCurrentId("");
        });
    }
  }

  const handleUpdate = (event) => {
    //TODO
  }
  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover className="product-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th className="image">Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {!!products && products.length > 0 ? (
          products.map((product, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{index}</td>
                <td>{product.image}</td>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.category}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>{product.description}</td>
                <td>
                  <Button onClick={handleDelete} btnText="Delete" />&nbsp;
                  <Button onClick={handleUpdate} btnText="Update" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })
        ) :
          (
            <tr><td className="center-title">Product list is empty!</td></tr>
          )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  )
}

export default ProductTableList;
```

Can anyone help me? How do I delete the product that I have selected

Can anyone explain or support for me why? Thank you so much

Comment: Have you tried this - <Button onClick={handleDelete(product.id)} btnText="Delete" />

Comment: Though you  never use the `id` argument passed to `handleDelete` either. Also, React recommends not using indexes for keys [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), rather use a unique property of product eg. `<tr key={product.id}>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a example, you need to add your function on button click and use your item id to be removed.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";

const ProductTableList = () => {

  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([{
          image: 'image',
          name: '01',
          category: '01',
          price: '01',
          description: '01'
        },
        {
          image: 'image',
          name: '02',
          category: '02',
          price: '02',
          description: '02'
        },
        {
          image: 'image',
          name: '03',
          category: '03',
          price: '03',
          description: '03'
        }])

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const removeItem = products.filter((item) => item !== products[id])
    setProducts(removeItem)
  }

  return (
    <Table striped bordered hover className="product-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th className="image">Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {!!products && products.length > 0 ? (
          products.map((product, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{index}</td>
                <td>{product.image}</td>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.category}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>{product.description}</td>
                <td>
                  <button onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}>Delete</button>&nbsp;
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })
        ) :
          (
            <tr><td className="center-title">Product list is empty!</td></tr>
          )}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  )
}

export default ProductTableList;
```

Also, avoid index as element key

```
{ items.map((item, index) => (<li key={index}>{item}</li>)) }
```

When a list item was added or removed, and the key kept the same, the React assumed that the DOM element had not changed, and the app could not render.

An alternative to cases that the list doesn't have a unique ID is to generate one using shortID.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid